# Javascript: How Do I Modify my JS to Resize Background Image to Stop Truncating the Edges?

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I currently have the following CSS in my stylesheet in my Rails 5 application.

```
#intro { 
    @media screen and (orientation: portrait) { padding: 25px 0; 
        background: url("portraitbackgroundimage.jpg");
    }
    @media screen and (orientation: landscape) { padding: 25px 0;
        background: url("landscapebackgroundimage.jpg");
    } 
}
```

I'm working on Javascript that will both shrink and expand the background image for responsive web design.

Here is my JS in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` which works okay except for truncating the right edge of the image a little bit.

```
var screenWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var screenHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
$('#intro').css('background-size', screenWidth+'px '+screenHeight + 'px');
```

I have also tried the following which also truncates the right edge of the image a little bit.

```
$('#intro').css('background-size', $(window).width()+'px '+$(window).height()+ 'px');
```

The original image only has maybe 10-20 pixels with no text on each edge. Depending on the size it is truncating the right of the image where the lettering is.

I have searched on Stack Overflow but so far have not found a solution.

Comment: So what is wrong with `background-size: contain` ?

Comment: I tried both contain and cover. Neither of them worked to shrink and expand the image. I originally had multiple images for portrait and landscape to take care of this but decided to develop a Javascript solution. I also realize that I need to add code to instantly execute the javascript when the browser window changes orientation such as when you rotate your mobile device.

Comment: If you set the `background-size` to the viewport dimensions then the image will be stretched/distorted (*if it is not of the exact same ratio*)

Comment: Although, if you are ok with the truncation from `background-size:cover` but want it to only happen on the left side, you can add `background-position: right center; `

Answer (score 0):

The images were slightly modified but I still had the issue with the truncating of the right side. I modified both the CSS and JS.

CSS

```
#intro { 
  @media screen and (orientation: portrait) { padding: 25px 0; 
        background: url("portrait.jpg") center center;
  }
  @media screen and (orientation: landscape) { padding: 25px 0;
        background: url("landscape.jpg") center center;
  } 
}
```

JS

```
function resizeIntroImage() {   
  var screenWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  var screenHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
  $('#intro').css('background-size', screenWidth+'px '+screenHeight + 'px');
}
resizeIntroImage();

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  resizeIntroImage();
}, false);
```

No truncation happens and the images resize when the browser window is resized.